# Haskell equivalent for python -m http.server?

Tags: haskell, httpserver, simplehttpserver, haskell-warp

Is there a way to start a http server to serve static files right from shell using ghc -e or runhaskell ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `wai-app-static` package ships with an executable named `warp`. This can be run from the command line to get a static file server. You can [look at its implementation](https://github.com/yesodweb/wai/blob/master/wai-app-static/app/warp-static.hs) to see how you can reimplement that behavior from `runhaskell`.

Answer (score 0):

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hserv is also an option, this also uses wai-app-static.

`cabal install hserve` and run `hserv`.